# Looking for a budget laptop for simple tasks

Tags: laptop

I need to buy a laptop for my wife, who will use it for the most basic of requirements: web surfing, email, word processing. It needs to run Windows, because she uses Microsoft Word extensively. It can have a small screen, say around 10-12 inches.

I don't want to spend much on this, but I want a machine that will be able to perform these simple tasks very well.

I have been burned in the past by buying devices like the [HP Stream](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-stream-11-ah110nr), which is advertised for precisely this use case, but totally inadequate. It doesn't have enough storage to handle even the operating system, and even with only a few browser tabs open, grinds to a halt. Even typing an email can bog down waiting for the keystrokes to process.

Obviously, I'd like to spend as little as possible, but not less than necessary to get a decent machine.

What is a good machine for this situation?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hw Recs! It would be more helpful to us if you posted a target price and/or a price limit.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't exactly know, because I've based decisions like this on price in the past, and found that my target was too low.

Comment: Post your target anyway. If it's too low we'll let you know and try to find the best middle ground for your needs!